# Making a cache decorator that supports a max size, expiration/ttl, and caches based on parameters

Tags: python, caching, memoization

I'm trying to build a cache for my python server but so far nothing I've come across combines everything that I want. I'd like a caching/memoization decorator that caches the result based on parameters, i.e. different parameters have different caches, and each cache expires after TTL minutes. There should also be a maximum size of the number of elements in the cache.

I've found this (we're on Python 2.7) and it does everything I want except expiration/TTL. 
[backport of Python 3's lru_cache](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578078-py26-and-py30-backport-of-python-33s-lru-cache/)

[gist of above code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0093c3b790e547b627ca)

I've tried to make some modifications to it to support TTL, but I'm running into errors in the LRU portion of the code where it's changing the links in the cache around. I don't think the above code requires many changes to add in TTL support, I'm just getting confused about the LRU cache stuff and having issues implementing it.

You can find my code [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1c98743711038aeb7966)

Has anyone implemented this before, or can maybe help me add support for TTL to the backport code above?

Thanks

Edit: I may have fixed it... I did some small changes [which you can find here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1339158b49b2089b3886), just separating the cache result from the LRU pointer stuff and it seems like it's working

Comment: Please include a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the exact problem you are experiencing in the question itself.  This includes code, error message, full traceback, etc.

Comment: have you found anything yet? How did you solve it?